# Where should I put my personal shell script in terms of safety?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

I am learning sh to make some customized function. I am looking for a safety location for the personal script, since I check from stack exchange, some say that put personal script under `~/bin` may explore to malicious software like make a `ls()` that really perform like `rm -rf`.

Comment: Yes, if you have run malicious software under your user account, it can modify any files in your `~/bin`. It can also modify your shell's startup files, like `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.profile`, along with any other similar configuration files of other programs.

Comment: Generally you cannot protect yourself from yourself. You can destroy your PC with a hammer for all I know.

Comment: If you want to protect your daily driver, install another OS on a Virtual Machine and learn there. In case you accidentally flunk something, you can just delete the VM and create a new one. As long as you keep the VM and your host OS separated you can''t damage the host.

Answer (score 0):

Edited following ilkkachu's comment. I forgot that write protection on a file doesn't protect it against deletion, so it also needs to be in a write-protected folder.

---

Your file will require a password to modify if

- only the owner has write permissions
- the owner is root

Even so, anyone can still delete the file, and then recreate it with their own content. To prevent that, the file needs to be placed in a folder without write permissions. And that folder could be deleted too, so it *also* needs to be in a protected folder, *etc* all the way up to `/`...

In other words, you want the file permissions to look like this:

`.rw-r--r-- root` which lets your normal user shell run it, but requires sudo to modify it; or

`.rwxr-xr-x root` if it also needs to be executable.

And all the containing folders between `/` and the file need to look like this:

`drwxr-xr-x root`

Fortunately, most of the top-level system folders outside of `home` fit the bill, since they're writeable by root only. I'm not sure what the convention says would be best, let's pick `/usr/share` for example.

So, starting from an ordinary file `~/myscripts/script.sh`:

```bash
# change file permissions to .rw-r--r--
chmod 644 myscripts/script.sh
# or to .rwxr-xr-x
chmod 755 myscripts/script.sh

# set permissions on the folder (they should be like this by default already)
chmod 755 myscripts

# make root the owner
sudo chown root:root myscripts/script.sh
sudo chown root:root myscripts

# place it in one of the root folders
sudo mv myscripts /usr/share/
```

If you're worried about that attack vector, you should make sure all your auto-run shell scripts are similarly protected: .bashrc, .bash_profile... (I don't know if it may give undesirable side-effects, haven't tried). You would also have to lock down any symlinks or config files that point to the new location.

Comment: but you'd also need them to remove write access to their home directory, as otherwise they can just remove and recreate the file using their own account